# How can i solve the Runtime Error "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library" in Outlook 2010 when i want to open an attached PDF with Adobe Reader?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, adobe-reader

I have a problem with my Outlook 2010 opening attached PDFs of e-mails.
When I want to open an attached PDF in an e-mail, I get a Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library  Error with the message:

```
Runtime Error!  
Program: D:\Microsoft\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE  
R6025 -pure virtual function call
```

How can I solve this problem?

I have the latest Adobe Reader, and the latest Microsoft Office Updates installed with Microsoft Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: I feel that this question doesn't belong on serverfault. However, you could try reinstalling the correct version of VCRT, then Outlook and finally Adobe Reader.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean with VCRT? Visual C++ Runtime Environment?

Comment: Yes, sorry for abbreviating. VCRT was meant to be Visual C++ RunTime